# EJS vulnerability in Electron

Tags: security, electron, ejs

We have application deployed using Electron for Singapore government project. We are having reported vulnerability for EJS, which is included in Electron that has critical vulnerability reported https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-29078.
We understand that from EJS perspective this is not the actual vulnerability, but application will be responsible for it. The question my client asks: is EJS used directly in Electron, hence Electron is exposed to this vulnerability, or is it only if the application using EJS deployed in Electron will be responsible?

We tried to build special version of Electron excluding EJS, but I think this may not be practical in term of long term maintainability. We intend to seek waiver but we need support from Electron team to affirm that Electron itself is not using EJS but only the application run on Electron that may be using and will be fully responsible on the actual vulnerability.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, if you need the Electron team to assure you something, better ask the Electron team directly, e.g. via [GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues).